# Select dropdown style function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function that styles select inputs by generating a div with an anchor, list and a hidden field:

```
function selectMenu() {

    var selectMenu = $("#cf-budget");

    $('<input id="' + selectMenu.attr("id") + '-hidden" type="hidden" name="' + selectMenu.attr("name") + '" value="" />').insertAfter(selectMenu);

    selectMenu.hide();
    var selectTitle =  selectMenu.children("option:eq(0)").text();
    var newSelectMenu = '<div class="selectmenu"><div class="selectmenu-selected"><a rel="placeholder">'+ selectTitle +'</a></div><ul class="selectmenu-menu"><li><a rel="placeholder">'+ selectTitle +'</a></li>';
    selectMenu.find("option:not(:eq(0))").each(function () {
        newSelectMenu += '<li><a rel="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + "</a></li>";
    });
    newSelectMenu += "</ul></div>";
    $(newSelectMenu).insertAfter(selectMenu);
    var newSelectMenu = $("div.selectmenu");

    $("div.selectmenu-selected a", newSelectMenu).live("click", function () {
        $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).toggle();
        return false;
    });
    $("body").live("click", function () {
        $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).hide();
    });
    $("ul.selectmenu-menu a", newSelectMenu).live("click", function () {
        var optionValue = $(this).attr("rel");
        var optionText = $(this).text();
        $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).hide();
        $("div.selectmenu-selected a", newSelectMenu).text(optionText);
        $("#" + selectMenu.attr("id") + "-hidden").val(optionValue);
        var activeMessageType = $("ul.message-type.active");
        if (activeMessageType.length) {
            activeMessageType.slideUp(300, function () {
                $("#" + optionValue).addClass("active").slideDown(300);
            }).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $("#" + optionValue).addClass("active").slideDown(300);
        }
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  selectMenu();
});
```

My question is how can I adjust this to make it work for 'x' amount of select inputs? Currently it only takes the Id or class of a single select.

I'm guessing I'd need to pass the function a select id or class name so that it can do it stuff to each dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a jsFiddle here for this that now is fully working: http://jsfiddle.net/7TaqN/1/

The suggestion by ach was perfect, however there was an issue with the body of your code. The following changes had to be made to make it work:

This line had to be removed as it overrode the 'this' selector:

```
 var selectMenu = $("#cf-budget");
```

This line had to be modified to select the class with the ID of the element clicked to 
prevent all elements from being affected:

```
 $(newSelectMenu).insertAfter(selectMenu);
 var newSelectMenu = $("div.selectmenu#"+ selectMenu.attr("id"));
```

This is the full working code as a jQuery module:

(Note this will only work with jQuery 1.8 as the .live() method you are using is deprecated in 1.9

```
$.fn.selectMenu = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var selectMenu = $(this);
        //Body of your selectMenu() function goes here
        //All selectors should be in the context of the selectMenu element
        $('<input id="' + selectMenu.attr("id") + '-hidden" type="hidden" name="' + selectMenu.attr("name") + '" value="" />').insertAfter(selectMenu);

        selectMenu.hide();
        var selectTitle = selectMenu.children("option:eq(0)").text();
        var newSelectMenu = '<div id="' + selectMenu.attr("id") + '" class="selectmenu"><div id="' + selectMenu.attr("id") + '" class="selectmenu-selected"><a rel="placeholder">' + selectTitle + '</a></div><ul class="selectmenu-menu"><li><a rel="placeholder">' + selectTitle + '</a></li>';
        selectMenu.find("option:not(:eq(0))").each(function () {
            newSelectMenu += '<li><a rel="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + "</a></li>";
        });
        newSelectMenu += "</ul></div>";
        $(newSelectMenu).insertAfter(selectMenu);
        var newSelectMenu = $("div.selectmenu#"+ selectMenu.attr("id"));

        $("div.selectmenu-selected a", newSelectMenu).live("click", function () {
            $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).toggle();
            return false;
        });
        $("body").live("click", function () {
            $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).hide();
        });
        $("ul.selectmenu-menu a", newSelectMenu).live("click", function () {
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("rel");
            var optionText = $(this).text();
            $("ul.selectmenu-menu", newSelectMenu).hide();
            $("div.selectmenu-selected a", newSelectMenu).text(optionText);
            $("#" + selectMenu.attr("id") + "-hidden").val(optionValue);
            var activeMessageType = $("ul.message-type.active");
            if (activeMessageType.length) {
                activeMessageType.slideUp(300, function () {
                    $("#" + optionValue).addClass("active").slideDown(300);
                }).removeClass("active");
            } else {
                $("#" + optionValue).addClass("active").slideDown(300);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mySelectClass').selectMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it into a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.selectMenu = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var selectMenu = $(this);
        //Body of your selectMenu() function goes here
        //All selectors should be in the context of the selectMenu element
    });
};
```

Then use it with standard jQuery selectors like so:

```
$('.mySelectClass').selectMenu();
```

Edit: Looks like you're already setting the context using the second parameter of `jQuery()` so additional use of `find` shouldn't be necessary.  That's a lot of code to parse through visually, though -- a jsfiddle might help.

<s>You'll also need to replace some of your selectors so that they're evaluated on the children of the `selectMenu` element, for example:</s>

```
selectMenu.find("div.selectmenu-selected a", newSelectMenu).live("click", function () {
```

Comment: This is good but I'm still clicking on one select and the others are responsing aswell

Comment: Any selector that is not operating on children of `selectMenu` needs to be modified to do so (see my edit for an example using `find()`).

Comment: Also, unrelated, but `live()` is deprecated.  You should use `on()` if on jQuery 1.7+ or `delegate()` if on 1.4.2+.